# HTTP client sending Expect and Upgrade headers simultaneosly

Tags: http, http-headers

Does HTTP/1.1 protocol regulate the case, when client sends both `Expect` and `Upgrade` headers at the same time? For example,  asking for permission to end  PUT operation and upgrade to HTTP/2.0 simultaneously. Should server send `100 Continue` and wait to HTTP/1.1 session to end, or should it start upgrading immediately? Is there any RFC, describing this situation?